# How can I use HTC Evo with Froyo to do USB tethering on the Mac?

Tags: android, tethering

After i connected the phone to my mac using the usb cord, i selected USB tethering.
I got an android phone dialog in the network preferences. I entered my sprint username/pass but nothing happened.

Using android 2.2 froyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB tethering is only officially supported in Android 2.2 for Windows and Linux machines. However, a number of people have gotten USB tethering to work on their OS X machines by downloading TUN drivers and OpenVPN software. See [Using Android Phone as a USB Tether on Mac OS X](http://thinkden.com/index.php/general/admin/75).